# To print prime numbers from the array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, primes

I want to create a program that will ask the user to input 5 integers using array and determine all the prime numbers entered. But I have difficulty with it. What seems to be the problem? I use JCreator for this.

```
package arrays;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Examples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Total numbers : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        boolean isPrime =true;
        int result =0;
        System.out.println("Enter the Numbers : ");
        int [] numbers = new int[n];
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            numbers[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=2;j*j<numbers[i];j++) {
                if(numbers[i]%j ==0) {
                    isPrime =false ;
                    break;  
                }
            }
        }
        if(isPrime) {
            System.out.println("The Prime Numbers : " +numbers[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Could you edit your question with more details about how your code doesn't work?

Comment: By the way, I would suggest putting the `if (isPrime)` part inside the second for loop (the outer one). Caching prime numbers also wouldn't hurt

Comment: You input multiple numbers but you have one isPrime value only

Comment: There's a problem in this line `System.out.println("The Prime Numbers : " +numbers[i]);` -- `i` is out of scope here

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question

Answer (score 2):

You should put the `isPrime()` inside the outer loop as below -

```
System.out.println("The Prime Numbers : ");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    isPrime =true;  // setting it to true before checking for every numbers
    for(int j=2;j*j<numbers[i];j++) {
        if(numbers[i]%j ==0) {
            isPrime =false ;  // will become false only when not an prime
            break;  
        }
    }
    // isPrime will remain true if numbers[i] is a prime number. So print the prime number
    if(isPrime) {
        System.out.println(numbers[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

You code had few errors -

```
if(isPrime) {
    System.out.println("The Prime Numbers : " +numbers[i]);
}
```

Firstly, the above piece of code wouldn't work, since the scope of `i` is limited only to the `for()` loop. Even if `i` was declared outside the for loop, the number that would have been printed would always have been last number (if a prime existed in the user inputted number). That is not we want.

So, print the numbers whenever you verify that a number is not prime. After you complete every inner loop, check the boolean `isPrime` and if it is true, we know that the number we are currently checking(`numbers[i]`) is surely a prime. So print the number there itself.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet fixes all the issues mentioned in the comments and checks only the odd numbers in the loop for primality:

```java
for (int num : numbers) {
    isPrime = num % 2 != 0 || num == 2;
    for (int j = 3; isPrime && j * j <= num; j += 2) {
        if (num % j == 0) {
           isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    if (isPrime && num > 1) {
        System.out.println("The Prime Number : " + num);
    }
}
```

You should also take into account that 0 and 1 are NOT primes.

---

More optimized way of primality check is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70473552/13279831) to a similar question: [Basic Java - Finding if a number is a prime number using while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70466662/).

Comment: Zero explanations, just doing his homework for him. That is not how you help people who want to learn programming. Solving all their problems for them slows their learning. Or did you learn programming because other people did the hard work for you?

Comment: @GhostCat which explanations are required here?? OP has almost completed his job and made some minor mistake that I pointed out in the comments.  This answer provides just an optimization to skip even numbers and don't count 0 as prime

Answer (score -1):

You need to check isPrime in outer loop

```
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {  // This loops for every number
       //inner both loops for check the number is prime
        boolean isPrime =true;
        for(int j=2;j*j<numbers[i];j++) {
            if(numbers[i]%j ==0) {
                isPrime =false ;
                break;  
            }
        }
        if(isPrime) {
           System.out.println("The Prime Numbers : " +numbers[i]);
        }
    }
```