# Basic Java - Finding if a number is a prime number using while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, primes

I have a question regarding an answer that was given here a while ago.
I came up with the same answer myself in the code attached but I'm trying to understand why do I need to divide the input number by 2 (line 10), and not just let the loop run its course till the value of the input number achieved.

```java
 1  import java.util.Scanner;            
 2  public class numIsPrime {
 3      public static void main(String[] args) {
 4          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 5          int i = 2; 
 6          boolean isPrime = true;
 7          System.out.println("Enter a number");
 8          int num = sc.nextInt();
 9        
10          while (i < num )   // (i <= num / 2)  
11          {
12              if (num % i == 0) 
13                  isPrime = false; 
14              i++;
15          }
16       
17          if (isPrime)
18              System.out.println(num + " is a prime number");
19          else // !isPrime
20              System.out.println(num + " isn't a prime number");
21
22      }
23  }
```

Comment: We do not have to divide `num` by `2` in the `while`-condition. It is just an optimization. Every factor of a number `n` has a "partner"-factor. Take for example `10` and its factor `2`. The "partner"-factor of `2` is `5` (because `2 * 5 = 10`). At least one of these factors must be `<= n / 2`. We can even further optimize by saying that `i * i <= num`. I leave the why as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, dividing by 2 is a simplest optimization to reduce the number of checks, however, existing code has a few issues (e.g. returning `true` for 0 and 1 which are NOT prime numbers) and may be further optimized:

- break/end the loop as soon as `isPrime` is set to `false`
- skip even numbers by incrementing by 2
- calculate until `i * i <= num`
  If this limit is reached, it means that no factor `i` of `num` has been found in the range `[2, num/i]`, therefore by definition of the prime numbers, all the remaining numbers in the range `[num/i, num]` are neither the factors of `num`, and therefore `num` is prime.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number");
int num = sc.nextInt();

boolean isPrime = num > 1 && (num % 2 != 0 || num == 2);
int i = 3;

while (isPrime && i * i <= num) {
    if (num % i == 0) 
        isPrime = false; 
    i += 2; // skip even numbers
}
if (isPrime)
    System.out.println(num + " is a prime number");
else 
    System.out.println(num + " isn't a prime number");
```

---

More optimizations are possible if the divisibles of 3 (except 3) are excluded similar to the exclusion of even numbers, then the search continues from 5 and the candidates for primality comply with `6n ± 1` rule (e.g., 5 = 6 - 1, 7 = 6 + 1, 11 = 12 - 1, 13 = 12 + 1, etc.):

```java
boolean isPrime = num > 1 && (num % 2 != 0 || num == 2) && (num % 3 != 0 || num == 3);
int i = 5;
int d = 2;

while (isPrime && i * i <= num) {
    if (num % i == 0) 
        isPrime = false; 
    i += d;    // check only non-even numbers
    d = 6 - d; // switch 2 to 4 and back to 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to calculate if an integer `n` is ***probably*** a prime:

```
public static boolean isPrime (int n) {
    if (n < 2) return false;
    BigInteger bigInt = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    return bigInt.isProbablePrime(100);
}
```

You can insert this function call in a loop where you can pass a new number every iteration. I am using the implementation of `BigInteger` provided by Java to do the calculation, rather than writing my own. UNLESS this is a homework and you are required to write your own algorithm, I would use this solution.

This base method can then be used for calculating other types of prime numbers. A complete answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258239/code-that-prints-all-prime-sophie-germain-prime-twin-prime-and-mersenne-prime/67258876#67258876).

**UPDATE**:

The `int` parameter in `BigInteger.isProbablePrime(int)` is a measure of the uncertainty that the caller is willing to tolerate. The larger the number, the "slower" it executes (but the more certain it is). Also, going back to the original question (already answered in the OP's comments section):

> **why do I need to divide the input number by 2 (line 10), and not just
> let the loop run its course till the value of the input number
> achieved.**

This is an optimization that will make your evaluation run twice as fast. For example, suppose an evaluation of `n` integers take 10 minutes to complete, excluding even numbers should take half the time. That's a significant improvement. Although you should not optimize prematurely, these sort of optimizations should be done right from the get go. Basically, we all know that even numbers are not prime, so why evaluate it? You want to evaluate unknowns. In my solution, I only evaluate values greater than 2 because by definition, values less or equal to 2 are not prime. I am merely solving that by definition or by mathematical properties.